# docker: unable to start container process: exec: "/entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown

Tags: docker

I run a docker image but it failed to create a container.

`docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown.`

It seems a problem of the permission of "/entrypoint.sh", however, I can not find entrypoint.sh.

btw, where can I see the log about running a container?

I've mount a disk to my device and I've change the docker path to the disk, I dont know if it's the problem.

Comment: Please post the command used to start container and anything else you did. Did you run it as root?